Cannot run Swift code on my windows system due to JIT session error
I'm getting a JIT session error when I'm running my swift program in vscode. How do I run this without the error?
My terminal
[Running] swift "d:\Metropolia\Swift_new\demo.swift"
JIT session error: Symbols not found: [ $ss27_allocateUninitializedArrayySayxG_BptBwlFyp_Tg5 ]
Failed to materialize symbols: { (main, { $sSa12_endMutationyyF, $ss5print_9separator10terminatoryypd_S2StFfA1_, $ss27_finalizeUninitializedArrayySayxGABnlF, $ss5print_9separator10terminatoryypd_S2StFfA0_, main }) }

I have installed swift from swift.org. I have enabled the developer tools option as well as installed the tools from visual studio community 2022 tools installer. I have enabled the swift extension in vscode as well. Kindly help me with this. I have swift version

Swift version 6.0.1 (swift-6.0.1-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-windows-msvc

I wanted to run a Hello world program.
Got this instead in myvscode terminal :
[Running] swift "d:\Metropolia\Swift_new\demo.swift"
JIT session error: Symbols not found: [ $ss27_allocateUninitializedArrayySayxG_BptBwlFyp_Tg5 ]
Failed to materialize symbols: { (main, { $sSa12_endMutationyyF, $ss5print_9separator10terminatoryypd_S2StFfA1_, $ss27_finalizeUninitializedArrayySayxGABnlF, $ss5print_9separator10terminatoryypd_S2StFfA0_, main }) }

[Done] exited with code=4294967295 in 0.12 seconds

